# How do I suppress automatic generated columns in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

When I assign a source (a DataTable) to a DataGridView, it automatically generates columns for each data column in the data table. But I only want the columns I defined manually.
How do I suppress the creation of the these columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to open the Column editor and uncheck the box Auto Generate Fields. Its towards the bottom left of the dialog.
[image: Columns]

If you are creating the gridview from code then there is a property:

```
DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

Answer (score 3):

In VS2008 there isn't a CheckBox for disabling auto-generate columns, though the generated code in InitializeComponent() has AutoGenerateColumns=false, but it still generates the unwanted columns!

How i fixed this was by editing the .resx file (View Code from the IDE) and removing the UserAddedColumn entries entirely. ie delete these entries:

```
<metadata name="Column1.UserAddedColumn" type=...>
  <value>True</value>
</metadata>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Name="myGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=...}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="Something" Binding="{...}" />
    .
    .
    .
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid
```

Comment: In general, you're right, but OP is talking about WinForms thus `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView` - not ASP.NET ;)

Comment: Oh, Okay.  Wel, this was the WPF approach and not even ASP.NET  :)